# Proving an inner product over the complex numbers

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Consider the vector space $V$ where $V$ is the set of continuous functions $f\colon [0,2] \to \mathbb{C}$. Prove that the following defines an inner product: $$(f \mid g) = \int_{1}^{2} f(x)\overline{g(x)}(1 + x^2)\,dx$$

My issue is the bounds of the integral. If we were dealing with $$(f \mid g) = \int_{0}^{2} f(x)\overline{g(x)}(1 + x^2)\,dx$$ then I would know how to continue but I'm confused as to how to do it when the bounds don't match.

Axioms for inner products:

1. $(f \mid f)$ $\geq$ 0 for all *a* $\in$ V
2. $(f \mid f)$ = 0 $\implies$ *f* = 0$_V$
3. Linearity in the first slot: $(f + \lambda h \mid g)$ = $(f \mid g) +\lambda(h \mid g)$
4. $(f \mid g)$ = $\overline{(g \mid f)}$

Comment: Yeah, axiom $(2)$ fails using $\int_1^2.$ For example $f(x)=(x-1)-|x-1|$ is nonzero on $(0,1),$ and zero on $[1,2].$

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to be an inner product space due to the bounds issue.  Note that if you let $f$ be piecewise linear,   $f(x)=1-x$ on $[0,1]$ and then $f(x)=0$ on $[1,2]$,  you get $(f|f)=0$.

The closest this could get to be an inner product space is if you took the equivalence class of functions that agree on $[1,2]$ as your vectors.  This would be isomorphic to the space of functions only defined on $[1,2$]  Likely there was a typo.